# can i create a part of a jsPDF file using html string?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jspdf

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>

   .... <other code> ....

   doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);       
   doc.text(first_name + " " + last_name, 10, 100);
   doc.text(company, 10, 120);
   doc.text(email, 10, 130);
   doc.fromHTML(april_2_html_table, 10, 140);
   doc.addPage();
```

where basically i have a string containing an html table, and i've saved it as "first_html_table".
I'd like to include this table in the PDF. This string is being generated dynamically.

I don't get an errors but basically everything except the table is appearing in the PDF.

EDIT 1

I'm currently getting an error message that says:

```
jspdf.min.js:63 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at k (VM1512 jspdf.min.js:63)
    at r (VM1512 jspdf.min.js:63)
    at VM1512 jspdf.min.js:63
    at i (VM1512 jspdf.min.js:63)
    at v (VM1512 jspdf.min.js:63)
    at x (VM1512 jspdf.min.js:63)
    at Object.e.fromHTML (VM1512 jspdf.min.js:63)
    at badgelist.forEach.badge (printbadges.php:153)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.onrendered (printbadges.php:122)
```

and my code can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/3AZZ3AYb
I'm trying to test just one record for one "badge" and i have verified in the console that all the data that i'm looking for is present. 
I have also tried to dump the contents of the first_html_table directly into .fromHTML() but that fails too.
I'm currently trying to narrow it down to a specific cell it doesn't like or something along those lines. 
I've removed all colspans and borders in the html but that hasn't really helped.
Any tips would be appreciated.

**EDIT 2**

It's definitely dying when i attempt to run the fromHTML() function. 
I've added two divs to the html and i populate the contents of the divs with the first_html_table and second_html_table.  everything looks right on screen.

The other thing i've done is added console debugs and i can definitely see that it's dying right when it calls the fromHTML method:

```
            console.log(first_html_table); //looks good
            console.log(badge['first_name']); //looks good
            $("#agenda1").html(first_html_table); //looks good
            $("#agenda2").html(second_html_table); //looks good
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);       
            doc.text(badge['first_name'] + " " + badge['last_name'], 10, 100);
            doc.text(badge['company'], 10, 120);
            console.log('got this far'); //works
            doc.text(badge['email'], 10, 130);
            console.log('afteremail');//works
            doc.fromHTML(first_html_table, 10, 160);  
            console.log("do you get here?"); //code doesn't get here
```

Comment: provided sample jspdf with html string in my post below, please share the html string which you have tried

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();

//var imgData = 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights'
var first_name = ''
var last_name = ''
var company = ''
var email = ''
var april_2_html_table = '<table><tr><td>1</td><td>ABC</td></tr></table>'

$('#show').click(function () {
  //doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', 10, 10);       
   doc.text(first_name + " " + last_name, 10, 100);
   doc.text(company, 10, 120);
   doc.text(email, 10, 130);
   doc.fromHTML(april_2_html_table, 10, 140);
   doc.addPage();  
    doc.save('sample.pdf');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
 Test</div>

<button id="show">Generate PDF</button>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/details/gEBjdq

Comment: @dot, can you console session , after this line - badge['sessiondata'].forEach(session => {

Comment: which seems to be undefined

Comment: If possible, please provide console of //console.log(badgelist);

Comment: To avoid this error for undefined session , add additional condition -   if (session && session['date'] == '2019-04-02')

Comment: but that part is in a for loop so if session doesn't exist it won't go enter right?

Answer (score 0):

the issue had to do with malformed HTML. 
the first row in my dynamic table only had one cell, whereas the others had 3.  so i had to add two empty cells to the first now and now it's happy.
ouf.